# How can I raise multiple error messages an Exception?

Tags: python, exception

I am doing some comparisons and storing error messages in a list. Then I check if this list if not empty, and if it is not, then I throw an `Exception`. The challenge I am facing is that I cannot think of how to `print` or `log` all of the error messages. Do I iterate over the list?

e.g.

```
error_messages = ['error_msg1', 'error_msg2', 'error_msg3'] 

if error_messages: 
    raise ValueError([error for error in error_messages])
```

If I run the above, I get `TypeError: unhashable type: 'list'`

The ideal output is that I get a log of each error message one by one, and that the `ValueError` exception is raised, as I would like the the code to break at that point.

Comment: `", ".join(error_messages)`!?

Comment: Thanks that works. I am now trying to line break using `\n` in the `join()` but it doesn't seem to work. Any ideas why this could be?

Answer (score 0):

For that, you have a library called `logging`. This is a default python library and you do not need to install it (normally).

```
import logging
logging.basicConfig(level=logging.DEBUG)

MY_FATAL_ERRORS = ['This error is fatal, it will raise an exception!', 'Other fatal error!']

def log_my_errors(error_msgs: list):
    fatal_errors = list()
    for error_number, error in enumerate(error_msgs):
        logging.error(f'[!] An error has occurred [{error_number}]: {error}')
        if error in MY_FATAL_ERRORS:
            fatal_errors.append(error)
    if fatal_errors:
        raise RuntimeError('Some errors occurred during the execution:\n' + '\n\t'.join(fatal_errors))
```

This piece of code prints your error in the logging console, even to a log file. This code also raises an exception if your error is fatal and you previously defined `fatal`. You can custom your error messages, take a look to the library doc for more information.

This code should work as follows:

```
MY_FATAL_ERRORS = ['This error is fatal', 'Oh :(', '404']
errors = ['A weak error', 'This error is not that bad', 'This error is fatal', 'Other error']

log_my_errors(errors)
```

```
ROOT:Error:  [!] An error has occurred [0]: A weak error
ROOT:Error:  [!] An error has occurred [1]: This error is not that bad
ROOT:Error:  [!] An error has occurred [2]: This error is fatal
ROOT:Error:  [!] An error has occurred [3]: Other error

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "...", line ..., in ...
    ...
  File "...", line ..., in ...
    raise RuntimeError('Some errors occurred during the execution:\n' + '\n\t'.join(fatal_errors))
RuntimeError: Some errors occurred during the execution:
    This error is fatal
```

In your code you cannot put a list inside an exception such as `ValueError()`, you must put a `string`. That is why I am converting a list to a string using `.join`. Your error message says that list is not hashable, because is trying to use it as a string. Provide a string and it will work.

Your code modified also works but it is not that ''elegant'' as using logging, which is probably what you really want to implement.

```
error_messages = ['error_msg1', 'error_msg2', 'error_msg3'] 

if error_messages: 
    raise ValueError('Errors:\n' + '\n\t'.join([error for error in error_messages]))
```

I hope it helped.

Comment: Thanks a lot, it does help. One thing though - the `\n` linebreak doesn't register for me. Does it register for you?

Comment: It's strange, when I use `join()` with `\n` in normal code and not in the Exception message it works, but when I use it in the exception message it doesn't work.

Comment: If `\n` is not working (in some cases it does not work like in PyCharm terminal) just use other separator. It could be ` - ` for example. But logging is by far the best way to trace errors.

Comment: `raise ValueError('Errors: ' + ' - '.join([error for error in error_messages]))`